# Proposal: GCD Tag Synonym Change

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

So I have been using SO for a while now and I have added both [grand-central-dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch) and [greatest-common-divisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor) tags to my favourite tags.

The questions related to the greatest common divisor are few and new questions really do not come along that frequently. At the time of this post there are 103 questions tagged with [greatest-common-divisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor).

On the other hand the [grand-central-dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch) tag currently has 1,485 questions... 1,382 more questions than [greatest-common-divisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor).

One of the reasons given for not changing the synonym is that a majority of people know that [gcd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcd) means greatest common divisor from their 8th grade math class. Except Stack Overflow is **not** a math site, it is a programming site, and how often outside of school do we really need detailed discussions of calculating the greatest common divisor?

Given that SO is a programming site should not the [gcd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcd) tag be used for something more programming related, namely Grand Central Dispatch related questions?

I only bring this up because I tend to check the [greatest-common-divisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor) questions frequently and often wind up changing the [greatest-common-divisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor) tag to [grand-central-dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch), which is what the question asker assumed the tag would be when they entered [gcd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcd).

I propose the [gcd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcd) tag be changed to [grand-central-dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch) from [greatest-common-divisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor) on the basis that Stack Overflow is a programming site, thus the use of [gcd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcd) there might make more sense to be a synonym for [grand-central-dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch) over [greatest-common-divisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor).

I mean, we can always edit erroneous uses of [gcd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcd) for math-related questions should they arise! Perhaps a new [gcd-math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcd-math) synonym could also be added for the [greatest-common-divisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor) tag should [gcd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcd) be changed.

I thought I would suggest this again because the last questions I could find are a good year old so thought it might be time to see what the general sentiment is now.

I added the [ambiguous-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ambiguous-tag) to this question as, to me, if people are consistently using [gcd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcd) to mean [grand-central-dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch) then the tag is ambiguous.

Comment: The edit to using the tag markup sure does make the line spacing very wonky with this many tags in the post. However, if it is the standard policy then so be it! ;)

Comment: It is not a dupe, I specifically stated I was asking the question again as all previous questions on the subject are over year old. After a year opinions may have changed, which is why I brought the subject up again.

Comment: Personally I'd favor nuking `gcd` altogether to eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: This is proposed in the comments at the earlier question, @Charles.

Comment: Previously closed as a duplicate of [Propose significant change in the definition of "gcd" tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165133) on Meta.SE

Comment: As this has been migrated back here to MSO, perhaps we could have a fresh discussion on the matter?

Comment: @Bhargav The answer asking for the synonym to just be removed (ie. that gcd isn't a valid tag anymore). What was completed?

Comment: @Braiam, Having [gcd] just nuked and lying around has a stronger chance for it to be recreated, as there is a combined total of more than 3500 questions. It is now synonymized to [grad-central-dispatch] as the OP originally requested.

Answer (score 10):

How about we just nuke the tag?

You've provided several reasons that the synonym should be changed, yet I immediately think "greatest common divisor" whenever I see "gcd" and I'm sure most other people do too. In fact, I've never even heard of "Grand Central Dispatch," whatever that is.

I think the best route is "kill with fire" because the percentage of people who will know what Grand Central Dispatch is *and* recognize GCD as an acronym for that instead of greatest common divisor is probably, what, 0.01%? Maybe 0.02?

So, the best way to resolve this ambiguity? Burninate!

Comment: This was already proposed at the earlier question, as well.

Comment: My point was that in the context of computer programming `gcd` is used to mean Grand Central Dispatch considerably more than it is used to mean Greatest Common Divisor. On any other site I could see leaving the `gcd` tag for the math problem, but on a programming site I really believe it would be better served as an acronym for a programming technology... or as others have suggested just remove the tag altogether.

Comment: @Eidola I have to disagree. As Doorknob points out, I think "gcd" is fairly standard abbreviation for "greatest common divisor". I have never heard of "Grand Central Dispatch". GCD, as in Greatest Common Divisor, is much more fundamentally related to programming than the other option. I'd even go as far as saying that "greatest-common-divisor" should be synonym to "gcd" rather than other way around.

Comment: @vhu As of this writing there are a total of 114 questions on "greatest-common-divisor" with the newest question being asked June 14th. For "grand-central-dispatch" there are 1,587 with 20 questions asked in the past month. Just because you have not heard of GCD does not mean it is not relevant. As I have stated, on any other site I can see "gcd" being for the math question, for a programming site I would of thought a programming technology would take priority... the numbers don't lie, "gcd" is used far more for Grand Central Dispatch than Greatest Common Divisor on Stack Overflow!